# Can I modify existing pages content in Rally

Tags: java, javascript, rally

In rally when I select any release its start_date and end_date should be automatically populated, rather than selecting it again.
So can I write code for that one and run it for our Rally instance.
any suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write code to make start and release dates populate automatically.
The behavior of "Create Release" page cannot be modified.
But releases can be created via Web Services API, e.g.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Release/create?key=abc123...
```

and payload:

```
{
"Release":{
"Name": "release0",
"ReleaseStartDate":"2014-05-14",
"ReleaseDate":"2014-05-30",
"State":"Planning"
}
}
```

Comment: Thnx nick for clarification..actully I don't want to modify "Create Release" page behaviour, while creating a feature u have a option to select release, and when you select the release "Planned start date" and "Planned end date" should automatically get selected.I want to write code for this, Is it possible?...Thnx in advance

Comment: agree, that makes more sense to populate automatically. But the answer is still no - the behavior of that page or any standard page cannot be changed.